# Why is my many-to-many collection not being passed through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I am creating a classroom system on Rails 6.  I have a many-to-many relationship with Units and Assignments.  I'm trying to create a form in Assignments where a unit (it's a many-to-many because I'll likely eventually make this a select multiple units) is selected in the assignment form.  Right now it works with no errors, but when I go into rails console, each assignment is getting no units after the form is submitted.

```
#Assignments Controller
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @assignment = Assignment.new
    end

    def create
        @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
        @assignment.save
        if @assignment.save
            flash[:success] = "The unit was successfully submitted."
            redirect_to units_path
        else 
            render 'new'
        end        
    end

    def show

    end


    private

    def assignment_params
        params.require(:assignment).permit(:name, :description, :duedate, unit_ids: [])
    end
end
```

It's the collection_select below I'm having the problem with.

```
#form
<%= form_for(@assignment, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do  |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <%= collection_select(:assignment, :unit_ids, Unit.all, :id, :name, placeholder: "Units" )%>
        </div>

        <div>
              <%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control", placeholder: "Title of Assignment", autofocus: true %> 
        </div>
        <div>
              <%= f.text_area :description, class:"form-control materialize-textarea", placeholder: "Assignment Description", autofocus: true %> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= f.text_field :duedate, class: "datepicker", placeholder: "Due Date"%>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="submitbutton">
            <div align = "center">
                <%= f.submit  class: "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Assignment model

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
      has_and_belongs_to_many :units
      has_many :users, :through => :units
end
```

Unit model

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :assignments
end
```

Let me know if there's more code needed.

Comment: This isn't really related to but you're calling `@assignment.save` twice in a row.

Comment: You also want to change the input to `f.collection_select(:unit_ids, Unit.all, :id, :name, placeholder: "Units" )` as that will bind the input to the model that the form wraps. Otherwise the input will always show all the units even when updating a record.

Comment: I am?  Does calling if @assignment.save also save it itself, not just check if it was saved?  Hm...I am learning rails through a udemy course and that's the way they taught to do it, but if i am calling it twice that's really good to know!

Comment: The second time it will just return true since there are no new changes to the record but its not its superfluous and kind of confusing. As an experience dev it makes me wonder what the heck is going on.

Comment: So you'd suggest deleting the first one?  Also I changed the code to what you said in the second comment, and the code still works without errors but I'm still not getting anything in terms of the assignment's units

Comment: Yes I do. Thats also in line with how rails generates scaffolds, the guides and 99% of Rails code out there. If you really wanted to split it into two lines for some reason it would make more sense to call `if @assignment.persisted?`. But really just `if @assignment.save` is such an engrained convention that I have no idea why they would question it.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong here. Look at the incoming parameters in the rails logs and try using byebug or pry to set a breakpoint and inspect assignment_params.

Comment: Great call on the byebug.  all parameters being passed, except I'm getting an "Unpermitted parameter: :unit_ids"  I'm going to search around on that, but do you know where the source would be?  It would seem it IS permitted under my controller.

Comment: Take a look at the `params` hash.